# Why is Hildreth's QP algorithm so simple?

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have Hildreth's [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming) (QP) algorithm and I find it very simple. Too simple so it becomes very much suspect. Why are this algorithm so simple, but other QP algorithms are complex and heavy, but still return the same result as Hildreth's QP algorithm.

```
function [x, solution] = quadprog(Q, c, A, b)
      % Assume that the solution is true
      solution = true;

      % Set number of iterations
      number_of_iterations = 255;

      % Same as in C code
      FLT_EPSILON = 1.19209290e-07;

      % Unconstrained solution
      x = -linsolve(Q, c);

      % Constraints difference
      K = b - A*x;

      % Check constraint violation
      if(sum(K <= 0) == 0)
        return; % No violation
      end

      % Create P
      P = linsolve(Q, A');

      % Create H = A*Q*A'
      H = A*P;

      % Solve lambda from H*lambda = -K, where lambda >= 0
      [m, n] = size(K);
      lambda = zeros(m, n);
      for km = 1:number_of_iterations
        lambda_p = lambda;

        % Use Gauss Seidel
        for i = 1:m
          w = -1.0/H(i,i)*(K(i) + H(i,:)*lambda - H(i,i)*lambda(i));
          lambda(i) = max(0, w);
        end

        % Check if the minimum convergence has been reached
        w = (lambda - lambda_p)'*(lambda - lambda_p);
        if (w < FLT_EPSILON)
          break;
        end

        % Check if the maximum iteration have been reached
        if(km == 255)
          solution = false;
          return;
        end
      end

      % Find the solution: x = -inv(Q)*c - inv(Q)*A'*lambda
      x = x - P*lambda;
    end
```

If I try an example:

```
% Objective function
Q = [1.200 -5.1000; -5.1000 26.0000];
c = [-2; -6];

% Constraints
A = [1 1; -1 2; 2 1];
b = [2; 2; 3];

% Hildreth's method
x = quadprog(Q, c, A, b)

% Internal QP-solver
[x, ~, info] = qp([], Q, c, [], [], [], [], [], A, b)
```

And the result was

```
  x =

   1.2842
   0.4315

  x =

   1.2842
   0.4315

  info =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    solveiter = 2
    info = 0
```

**Question:**

Hildreth's QP algorithm gives the same result as other QP algorithms. So why should I use for example KTT conditions and such other advanced things, if Hildreth's QP algorithms does the job?

Comment: "% Assume that the solution is false
      solution = true;". Simple alright.

Comment: @Raskolnikov It's now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If $Q$ is positive definite, one approach (which is even simpler than Hildreth's algorithm) is to transform the problem into a form which can be solved using Matlab's `lsqnonneq()` function.

Given the QP problem
$$\eqalign{
\min_x\;&\tfrac 12x^TQx + c^Tx \\
{\rm s.t.}\;&Ax \le b \\
}$$
calculate the Cholesky factorization $Q=L^TL$ and the following variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\L{L^{-1}}
\def\Q{Q^{-1}}
\def\e{{\large\rm e}_1}
f = b + A\Q c,\qquad 
\e=\m{{\tt1}\\ c-c},\qquad 
M = A\L,\qquad 
P = \m{-f^T \\ -M^T} \\
}$$
Formulate the Non-Negative Least Squares problem
$$\eqalign{
\min_w\;&\|Pw-\e\|^2_2 \\
{\rm s.t.}\;&w \ge 0 \\
}$$
The solution of which is $\;w={\rm lsqnonneg}(P,\e)$

The solution of the original QP problem is
$$\eqalign{
x &= -\Q\left(c+\frac{A^Tw}{{\tt1}+w^Tf}\right) \\
}$$
However, if $\:Pw=\e\:$ then the problem is **infeasible**.

$\sf NB\!:\:$ The above method was described in [this paper](https://iris.imtlucca.it/bitstream/20.500.11771/3559/1/qp_nnls_Final.pdf) by Alberto Bemporad.

### Update

Here is the pseudocode for the Sequential Coordinate-wise Algorithm.

Initialize
$$\eqalign{
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\ek{{\large\varepsilon}_k}
z &= -P^Te_1 \\
w &= \LR{z-z} \,\equiv\, 0 \\
}$$
Iterate
$$\eqalign{
&{\rm for\;} i = 1:{\large i}_{max} \\
&\qquad y = w \\
&\qquad{\rm for\;} k = 1:n \\
&\qquad\qquad f = P^TP\ek \\
&\qquad\qquad \alpha = \min\LR{w_k,\;\frac{z_k}{f_k}} \\
&\qquad\qquad w = w - \alpha\ek \\
&\qquad\qquad z \:=\, z - \alpha f \\
&\qquad{\rm end} \\
&\qquad{\rm if}\LR{{\|w-y\|_\infty\le 10^{-12}}}\;{\rm return\;}w \\
&{\rm end} \\
}$$
where $\ek$ denotes the $k^{th}$ euclidean basis vector and
$\LR{f_k,z_k}$ are the $k^{th}$ components of their respective vectors. The presence of ${\large i}_{max}$ prevents infinite looping.

Comment: Cool! Did not know that. But Non-Negative Least Squares is computationally expensive. I don't think that method is much after than Hildreths algorithm, even if they give the same result back.

Comment: Beyond Matlab's built-in function, there are many other algorithms for NNLS which are useful for large problems. The best performing is probably projected gradient descent using _Barzilai-Borwein_ steps, and the simplest is the _Sequential Coordinate-Wise_  algorithm by Franc, Hlavac, Navara.

Comment: Wow! Sounds very nice, can you some some examples so I can try it? I don't have MATLAB, only Octave.

Comment: [This paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/doc/10.1.1.157.9203) contains pseudocode for lots of different NNLS algorithms that you can implement in Octave.  The _Sequential Coordinate-Wise_ algorithm is on page 76.

Comment: Thank you for the paper! I did try to run that algoritm, but I think somethings might be right. Can you check this MATLAB code? https://pastebin.com/PYvGZZUc The nnls algorithm seems to do the job. The $x$ solution is not correct.

Comment: I can't spot the error in your code, but I see that you chose the Lawson/Hanson active-set algorithm which is rather tricky.  I would recommend the Sequential Coordinate-Wise algorithm, which is extremely simple.

Comment: Hi. There was only one error in my code. The minu sign should be `+`. But even if I changed it, it did not turn into the correct value `x = -inv(Q)*(c - (A'*w)/(1 + w'*f))`. It's an error in your math, I guess. Yes, it's a more tricky algorithm, but it seems to work very well. I trided  Sequential Coordinate-Wise algorithm and it requries an initial guess $x_0$.

Comment: In the Sequential Coordinate-Wise algorithm, the initial value is **always** zero, i.e. $x_0=0\;$

Comment: Can you post a Matlab example?